# Kendo Ui Hierarchy data issue

Tags: php, kendo-grid, hierarchy

I have an issue with displaying a "details" type grid shown here:
http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/grid/hierarchy

For the sake of keeping this as short as possible I will show a sample data set in array form:
`//$data['kendoList']['companies'] =
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => MyCompany
            [sub_domain] => myco
            [company_logo_180] => myco_180.png
            [company_logo_100] => myco_100.png
            [company_logo_70] => myco_70.png
            [status] => Active
            [created] => 2012-08-27 08:42:15
            [modified] => 2014-05-14 15:24:03
            [client_id] => 1
            [Logo] => /media/myco/logos/myco_180.png
            [company_id] => 20
            [InspCount] => 3017
            [ItemCount] => 1864
            [UserCount] => 2
            [AdvCount] => 2
            [ProjectCount] => 0
            [client] => MyClient
        )
//$data['kendoList']['plants'] = 
     [0] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 20
            [name] => MyPlant
            [plant_prefix] => myplant
            [image] => myplant-map.png
            [mappdf] => myplant-mappdf.pdf
            [icon_on] => myplant_on.png
            [icon_off] => myplant_off.png
            [status] => Active
            [supports] => onshore
            [measurements] => Feet
            [created] => 2012-08-27 09:57:57
            [modified] => 2012-12-14 13:44:53
            [Logo] => /media/myplant/facilities/myplant-map.png
            [plant_id] => 37
            [InspCount] => 3018
            [ItemCount] => 1865
        )`

The strange thing about this is the InspCount and ItemCount fields will be distinguishable as in the can be forced in the build up of this data to have different counts and actually show properly on the grid. On the other hand, the field Logo in plants, which are supposed to be a child of company, will have the same value as the Logo field in companies. Here goes the code for the printout. Three of us, the other two having significantly more experience with Kendo than myself, are scratching out heads.

```
<style>

    .k-grid-header th.k-header > .k-link {
        text-decoration:    none;
    }
</style>
<?php
if(isset($data["kendoList"]["companies"])) {

    $status = '<div class="tileThis #=status#">#:status#</div>';
    $columnsSetCo = array(
        array('width' => 80, 'filterable' => false,
            'template' => '<img src="#=Logo#?'.time().'" alt="logo" style="max-height: 70px; max-width: 70px;" height="70" />'),
        array('field' => 'name', 'title' => ucfirst($data['companies']["name_ui_s"]).' Name'),
        array('field' => 'client', 'title' => 'Client', 'hidden'=>true),
        array('field' => 'company_id', 'title' => 'company_id', 'hidden'=>true),
        array('field' => 'UserCount', 'width' => $colWidths["InspCount"], 'title' => 'Users', 'filterable' => false),
        array('field' => 'AdvCount', 'width' => $colWidths["AdvCount"], 'title' => 'Facilities', 'filterable' => false),
        array('field' => 'ProjectCount', 'width' => $colWidths["ProjectCount"], 'title' => 'Projects', 'filterable' => false),
        array('field' => 'ItemCount', 'width' => $colWidths["ItemCount"], 'title' => 'Items', 'filterable' => false),
        array('field' => 'InspCount', 'width' => $colWidths["InspCount"], 'title' => 'Inspections', 'filterable' => false),
        array('field' => 'status', 'width' => $colWidths["Status"], 'template' => "$status")
    );
    if($data["kendoList"]['canEdit']){
        $edit = "<a href='".$this->Html->url(route_array('companies', 'edit', 'admin', array('#=company_id#')))."'><div class='tileThis edit'>Edit</div></a>";
        $columnsSetCo[] = array('field' => '', 'width' => 70, 'template' => $edit);
    }

    $grid = $this->Kendo->prepareGrid($data["kendoList"]["companies"], $columnsSetCo, array(
        'name' => 'companyGrid',
        'default_column_settings' => array(
            'attributes' => array('class' => 'center')
        ),
        'data_source' => array(
            'addFilterItem' => array('field' => 'status', 'operator' => 'eq', 'value' => 'Active'),
            'addGroupItem' => array('field' => 'client', 'dir' => 'asc')
        ),
        'grid_settings'=>array(
            'detailTemplateId'=>'details'
        ),
    ));
    echo $grid->render();

    echo "<script id='details' type='text/x-kendo-template'>";
        //Build the facility list
        $status = '<div class="tileThis #=status#">#:status#</div>';
        $columnsSetFac = array(
            array('width' => 80, 'filterable' => false,
                'template' => '<img src="#=Logo#" alt="logo" style="max-height: 70px; max-width: 70px;" height="70" />'),
            array('field' => 'name', 'title' => ucfirst($data['plants']["name_ui_s"]).' Name'),
            array('field' => 'company_id', 'title' => 'company_id', 'hidden'=>true),
            array('field' => 'ItemCount', 'width' => $colWidths["ItemCount"], 'title' => 'Items', 'filterable' => false),
            array('field' => 'InspCount', 'width' => $colWidths["InspCount"], 'title' => 'Inspections', 'filterable' => false),
            array('field' => 'status', 'width' => $colWidths["Status"], 'template' => "$status")
        );
        if($data["kendoList"]['canEdit']){
            $edit = "<a href='".$this->Html->url(route_array('plants', 'edit', 'admin', array('#:plant_id#')))."'><div class='tileThis edit'>Edit</div></a>";
            $columnsSetFac[] = array('field' => '', 'width' => 70, 'template' => $edit);
        }
        $detailGrid = $this->Kendo->prepareGrid($data["kendoList"]["plants"], $columnsSetFac, array(
            'name' => 'detailGrid#=company_id#',
            'default_column_settings' => array(
                'attributes' => array('class' => 'center')
            ),
            'data_source' => array(
                'addFilterItem' => array('field' => 'company_id', 'operator' => 'eq', 'value' => '#=company_id#')
            ),
            'grid_settings'=>array(
                'groupable'=>false
            )
        ));
        echo $detailGrid->renderInTemplate();
    echo "</script>";
    }
```

The prepare grid was built by another employee as a grid helper. We have never had an issue with it but for completeness:

```
<?php

/**
 * Kendo Helper
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * @category Helper
 * @version  1.0
 */
class KendoHelper extends AppHelper
{
    private $_utilities = null;

    public function __construct($options = null) {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->_utilities = ClassRegistry::init('UtilitiesComponent');
    }

    /**
     * Prepares a Kendo Grid with some common defaults and takes in data and columns from array
     * It also knows if there is no title. It makes a title based on the field value.
     * By default it sets this settings in the grid:
     *   * scrollable = false
     *   * sortable = true
     *   * groupable = true
     *   * resizable = true
     *   * filterable = array('extra' => false)
     *   * pageable = array('pageSize' => 25, 'pageSizes' => array('25', '50', '100'))
     *
     * @param array $dataArr Array of arrays. Array with row of data with the key being the field name.
     * @param array $columnsArr Array of arrays. The array elements have key-value pair for method-param respectively.
     * @param array $options To change the output of the function
     * @return \Kendo\UI\Grid The prepared grid to use.
     */
    public function prepareGrid(array $dataArr, array $columnsArr = array(), $options = array())
    {
        $options = array_merge(array(
            'name' => 'grid',
            'default_column_settings' => array(),
            'data_source' => array(),
            'extra_field_types' => array(),
            'grid_settings' => array()
        ), $options);
        $options['grid_settings'] = array_merge(array(
            'scrollable' => false,
            'sortable' => true,
            'groupable' => true,
            'resizable' => true,
            'filterable' => array('extra' => false),
            'pageable' => array('pageSize' => 25, 'pageSizes' => array('25', '50', '100'))
        ), $options['grid_settings']);

        $options['name'] = empty($options['name'])
            ? 'grid-'.substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 0, 8)  : $options['name'];

        $grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid($options['name']);
        $columns = array();
        $modelFields = array();

        //# Setup extra fields
        if(!empty($options['extra_field_types'])) {
            foreach($options['extra_field_types'] as $field => $type) {
                $modelField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField($field);
                $modelField->type($type);
                $modelFields[] = $modelField;
            }
        }

        //# Setup the Columns and Models
        foreach($columnsArr as $col){
            $gridCol = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
            //http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/model#methods-Model.define
            //The available options are "string", "number", "boolean", "date". The default is "string"
            $type = 'string';

            //get the type
            if(isset($col['value_type'])) {
                $type = $col['value_type'];
                unset($col['value_type']);
            } elseif (isset($col['field'])) {
                $field = Set::extract($dataArr, '0.' . $col['field']);
                $val_type = gettype($field);
                switch($val_type) {
                    case 'boolean':
                        $type = 'boolean';
                        break;
                    case 'integer':
                    case 'double':
                    case 'float':
                        $type = 'number';
                        break;
                    case 'object':
                        $type = ($val_type instanceof DateTime) ? 'date' : 'string';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $type = 'string';
                        break;
                }

                //if there is not a title use the field name
                if(!isset($col['title'])) {
                    $col['title'] = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', join(' ', preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $col['field']))));
                }
            }

            $col = array_merge($options['default_column_settings'], $col);

            foreach($col as $method => $value) {
                if(in_array($method, get_class_methods($gridCol))) {
                    $gridCol->{$method}($value);
                }
            }

            if(isset($col['field'])) {
                $modelField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField($col['field']);
                $modelField->type($type);
                $modelFields[] = $modelField;
            }
            $columns[] = $gridCol;
        }

        //# Setup datasource
        $dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\DataSource();

        if(count($modelFields) > 0) {
            $model = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModel();
            call_user_func_array(array($model, 'addField'), $modelFields);
            $schema = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchema();
            $schema->model($model);
            $dataSource->schema($schema);
        }

        if (count($dataArr) > 0) {
            $dataSource->data($dataArr);
        }

        if(!empty($options['data_source'])) {
            foreach($options['data_source'] as $method => $value) {
                if(in_array($method, get_class_methods($dataSource))) {
                    $dataSource->{$method}($value);
                }
            }
        }

        if(count($columns) > 0) {
            call_user_func_array(array($grid, 'addColumn'), $columns);
        }

        $grid->dataSource($dataSource);

        if(!empty($options['grid_settings']) && is_array($options['grid_settings'])) {
            foreach($options['grid_settings'] as $method => $setting){
                if(in_array($method, get_class_methods($grid))) {
                    $grid->{$method}($setting);
                }
            }
        }

        return $grid;
    }

    /**
     * For $items_tree each node (array) can have MenuItem methods names as keys. Except for startContent and endContent.
     * An extra key is items. It holds the sub items that are nested in that item.
     * Example:
     *
     * [
     *   ['text' => 'HOME', 'url' => '/'],
     *   ['text' => 'ITEMS', 'items' => [
     *     ['text' => '<b>NEED APPROVAL</b>', 'url' => '/items/approve'],
     *     ['text' => '<b>DISABLED</b>', 'url' => '/items/?disabled'],
     *     new \Kendo\UI\MenuItem('text')
     *   ]]
     * ]
     *
     * @param $name
     * @param array $items_tree Tree (array) of menu items (arrays or MenuItems)
     * @param array $options
     * @return \Kendo\UI\Menu
     */
    public function prepareMenu($name, array $items_tree, array $options = array())
    {
        $menu = new \Kendo\UI\Menu($name);

        //configure menu
        foreach($options as $method => $value) {
            if(method_exists($menu, $method)) {
                $menu->{$method}($value);
            }
        }

        if(empty($items_tree)){
            return $menu;
        }

        //Adding items, recursively if they are nested
        $menu = $this->recursiveMenuItemInsertion($menu, $items_tree);

        return $menu;
    }

    /**
     * It uses the keys has_access to figure out if an item should be filtered out.
     * If this key doesn't exist, the item is not filtered out.
     * If the has_access exist, it's boolean value tells the function to filter it out (false) or not.
     * @param array $items_tree
     * @return array
     */
    public function filterMenuItemsByAccess(array $items_tree)
    {
        //by reference so that we can unset it, plus it doesn't create a copy of the array
        foreach($items_tree as $i => &$cur_item) {
            //recur nested items
            if(isset($cur_item['items']) && is_array($cur_item['items']) && !empty($cur_item['items'])){
                $cur_item['items'] = $this->filterMenuItemsByAccess($cur_item['items']);
            }

            if(isset($cur_item['has_access'])) {
                //Does it have access
                $has_access = (bool)$cur_item['has_access'];

                if(!$has_access) {
                    unset($items_tree[$i]);
                } else {
                    unset($cur_item['has_access']);
                }
            }
        }

        return $items_tree;
    }

    /**
     * This tries to process nested menu items (array) in a recursive form to add them into its parent,
     * @param \Kendo\UI\Menu|\Kendo\UI\MenuItem $parent_item
     * @param array $items_tree
     * @return \Kendo\UI\MenuItem|\Kendo\UI\Menu|mixed Whatever $parent_item is
     */
    public function recursiveMenuItemInsertion($parent_item, array $items_tree)
    {
        if(!($parent_item instanceof \Kendo\UI\MenuItem || $parent_item instanceof \Kendo\UI\Menu)){
            return $parent_item;
        }

        foreach($items_tree as $cur_item) {
            if($cur_item instanceof \Kendo\UI\MenuItem) {
                $menuItem = $cur_item;
            } elseif(is_array($cur_item)) {
                $menuItem = new \Kendo\UI\MenuItem();
                $methods = array_diff_key($cur_item, array('items' => true));

                //configure item
                foreach($methods as $method => $value) {
                    if(method_exists($menuItem, $method)) {
                        $menuItem->{$method}($value);
                    }
                }

                //Deal with nested items
                if(isset($cur_item['items'])){
                    $menuItem = $this->recursiveMenuItemInsertion($menuItem, $cur_item['items']);
                }
            }

            if(isset($menuItem)){
                //add to parent, either menu or an item
                /** @var \Kendo\UI\Menu|\Kendo\UI\MenuItem $parent_item */
                $parent_item->addItem($menuItem);
            }
        }

        return $parent_item;
    }
}
```